# Adding a string to a collection of strings while debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have an empty collection of strings, a list. I'd like to add a string item to it, but I can't see anyway how to.

The tools on the screen, QuickView, don't proffer that functionality, I've tried to use the 'Immediate Window' to do it manually but there was no function I could call to add a new string with.

Comment: What happened when you *tried* with the immediate window?

Comment: What did you immediate window attempt look like?

Comment: What command did you run in the immediate window? What is the response after you hit enter?

Comment: My bad, I'm new to using 'Immediate Window', I had merely mistaken List<string>, for IEnumerable<string>. Ouch! A quick cast and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
var stringCol = new Collection<String>();
```

or

```
var stringCol = new List<String>();
```

*(Are you using something other than a Collection<> or a List<> ?)*

You will be able to set a breakpoint on a line AFTER this declaration, and type **stringCol.Add("blahblah");** in your Immediate Window, and this will add the item to the Collection or List.  Once you hit enter, the result will say something like "Expression has been evaluated and has no value", but if you check your list, the new item will be there.

You can also hit ctrl+space after you type **stringCol.** to pull up the intellisense options.

Another thing that might work for you, is to insert debugging symbols directly in the code like so:

```
#if DEBUG

   //manipulate your string collection here, only while in DEBUG mode
   //set breakpoints so you can skip over this code while debugging, if desired

#endif
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'm new to manipulating code via the 'Immediate Window', what I had assumed was a List<string>, was in this instance a IEnumerable<string>. As commented above a quick cast to List<string> and in my new value went.